# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()

Tags: php, laravel-5, error-handling

> Call to undefined function `Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()`

Laravel Throws that error when I start project after changing the PHP version from 7.1.1 to 7.2.4